# Galeria em pagina wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Queria um plugin para wordpress que exibisse minha galeria de mídia em uma página para todos verem. Tem como fazer isso direto, ou alguém conhece algum plugin para isso?

Comment: O WP tem uma galeria nativa. É só clicar "Inserir midia" pra gerenciar isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o NextGEN Gallery que tem uma versão gratuita.
Ele é simples de usar e você consegue otimizar suas imagens como desejar.

Esse é o site do plugin **[www.nextgen-gallery.com](http://www.nextgen-gallery.com)**. Para maiores explicações basta ler a documentação que se encontra no endereço **[www.nextgen-gallery.com/help/](http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/help/)**

Caso queira ver alguns exemplos rodando visite **[www.nextgen-gallery.com/wordpress-gallery-plugin/](http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/wordpress-gallery-plugin/)**